# String and CharStream<'a> in FParsec

Tags: f#, fparsec

I would like to parse a big sentence, which can contain names in fsharp.
I posit that names is in the form first name + last name.
In the absence of a first name list (can't find, will do later), I say that a first name is a string of length 4 or more, same for the last name.

When I try my very smart parser

```
let firstorlastname x = (parray 4 letter)  x
firstorlastname "JEAN"
firstorlastname "CHRISTOPHE"
```

So, it works for both, but the problem is that it consumes only 4 characters, which is not the desired behaviour for Christophe. I would like the whole word to be consumed.

How can I instruct FParsec to consume the entire word, but fail if the word is less than 4 characters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but I think this should do it:

```
let firstOrLastName = manyMinMaxSatisfy 4 Int32.MaxValue isLetter
```